# DSATUR graph coloring algorithm input ( Matlab code )

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I'm trying to run   a Matlab code of  DSATUR graph coloring algorithm that I found in:       http://armanboyaci.com/?p=487   where its inputs are: V(vertices ) and E(edges) , however when I tried to use an input such as : E=
                                 [1 2]
                                 [2 3]
                                 [3 4]
                                 [1 4];    and V=[ 4,2,3,1]; I always having error    ,  my question: is my input is wrong? if yes, how should the right input  look like?

thanks in advance

Comment: Is this code still available? Could you provide the link in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Matlab multi-dimensional arrays are [defined](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html) with single square brackets and semicolon to separate rows.

As I don't have Matlab at my disposal the same with GNU Octave

```
octave:1> E= [1 2; 2 3; 3 4; 1 4];
octave:2> V=[4,2,3,1];
octave:3> dsatur(E,V)
ans =

   1
   1
   1
   2
```

Comment: Thank you divanov,  same old problem, anyway , thank you again for sharing .

Answer (score 0):

The MATLAB code you have linked to can be used as follows

```
E=[1 2; 2 3; 3 4; 1 4];
V=[4; 2; 3; 1];
>> dsatur(V,E)
ans =
     1
     2
     1
     2
```

That is, nodes 4 and 3 are colour 1, and nodes 2 and 1 are colour 2. NB: the vertex list must be a column vector and the function arguments require V before E.